# Wordpress How to get ACF relationship with WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my `Wordpress` application I have a custom field called "departments" in which there is a relationship field called "department_customer" - which should return the customer the department is assigned to. I tried to do this:

```
$departments = new WP_Query([
   'post_type' => 'department',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query' => [
     [
       'key' => 'department_customer',
       'value' => (int) $post->ID,
       'type' => 'NUMERIC',
       'compare' => '='
     ]
  ],
]);
```

and then loop through:

```
foreach($departments->posts as $department){
    echo $department; // just for testing if something returns
}
```

but this return nothing... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this documentation could help you :

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Maybe you could try something like :

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'department_customer',
    'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
  )
)
```